# When to use "he know" and "he knows"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, conjugations

Well I just read book in my friend house and there I notice that there was sentence like

> He knows how to do that task

but what if I use it like

> He know how to do that task

That thing is still confusing me and I don't the key difference because I am just in process of learning.

Comment: The key difference is: _he know_ is wrong. With he/she/it, the correct verb form is _knows_.

Comment: and what if we talk about past like `he knew` ?

Comment: In the simple past, the verb form is the same (_knew_) for I/you/he/she/it/we/you/they indeed. But your example is simple present, and then most verbs take an -s for he/she/it.

Comment: The forms of present tense  http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/simplepresentforms.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that I am adding anything new here, but this may clear up a couple of points.

In the present simple (affirmative), the form used for all persons except the third person singular of all verbs (except BE and the modals) is the same as first form/base form/bare infinitive:

```
I        know/play/try/do/wash 
you      know/play/try/do/wash  
we       know/play/try/do/wash
they     know/play/try/do/wash
```

In the third person singular of all verbs (except BE and the modals), an **-s** is added to the first form. There may be other slight changes, such as the addition of an **e** before the **-s**, but there is always an **-s** ending:

```
he          knows/plays/tries/does/washes
she         knows/plays/tries/does/washes
it          knows/plays/tries/does/washes     
the boy     knows/plays/tries/does/washes
the girl    knows/plays/tries/does/washes
Peter       knows/plays/tries/does/washes
```

In the negative and interrogative form, we use the bare infinitive of the verb with the auxiliary DO. It is the auxiliary that adds the ending in the third person singular:

*I/you/we/they do not know, do not play, do not try, do not do, do not wash*

*he/she/it/the boy/the girl/Peter does not know, does not play, does not try, does not do, does not wash*

*Do I/you/we/they know?, play?, try?, do?, wash?*

*Does he/she/it/the boy/the girl/Peter know?, play?, try?, do?, wash?*

Answer (score 4):

If you still want to use he and know in one sentence , then you can use something like this

"he does know how to do that task"

by using "does" here, we are emphasizing the fact that he knows..

Usually this is done when someone asks a question.

Does he know how to do that task?

He knows how to do that task.

OR

He does know how to do that task.

Both replies convey the same meaning.

consider this

Person A to B: I don't think he knows how to do that task.

Person B to A: You are wrong. He does know how to do that task.

( Person B is emphasizing the fact that he knows how to do that task and in doing so letting ( or emphasizing/stressing) the person A know that she is wrong )

Answer (score -1):

"Know" is the plural form of the verb. Plural forms are also used with declarative statements involving yourself as the subject, and imperative commands.

> I know exactly what you're talking about.
>
> We don't know who passed through last evening, officer.
>
> Know this: I won't stand for your buffoonery any longer!

"Knows" is the singular, present-tense form of the verb.

> I think he knows exactly what you mean.

However, there are certain sentence structures where "know" will be used with a plural form against a singular subject:

> How did Jacob know what you were planning?
>
> There's no way he could know that.

It seems like you're asking about some very fundamental rules. You should probably take a formal class on English; this website is meant for those already learning English to ask questions to fill in the gaps, not to learn English with little-to-no knowledge going in.

Comment: I find it very confusing to tell people that _know_ is a "plural" form. And then add it is also used for blablabla involving yourself. No. You forget the _you_ singular form, for starters. It's a lot easier to just say that _know_ is used for all persons and numbers, except 3rd person singular (he/she/it). Less words, and I _think_ a bit simpler. "know" will be used with a plural form against a singular subject:" You mean to say that sometimes you use the infinitive?

Comment: An overview of English verb inflection can be found in one of the freely available chapters of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*: [Start on page 8 of the PDF file](http://www.cambridge.org/assets/linguistics/cgel/chap2.pdf), which is page 50 in the book.